# Implementation of convolution matrix-matrix multiplication in Caffe

Tags: caffe

I have read that Caffe implements convolution operation as a matrix-matrix multiplication. I have unsuccesfully been plowing through the Caffe source code. Where can I find the implementation and the use of the multiplication in the forward step?

Comment: look into `src/caffe/layers` for convolutional layer three types of implementation (`cpu,cuda,cudnn`) are respectively in `conv_layer.cpp,conv_layer.cu,cudnn_conv_layer.cu`.